# How to define Endpoints for multiple Service contracts implemented in different classes?

Tags: wcf

I have taken a WCFService library in which I have defined multipled service contracts(interfaces) in separate cs files and implemented them separately. For example ..

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
     [OperationContract]  
    string GetService1Msg();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService2
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetService2Msg();
}
```

I have defined above interfaces in separate cs files.Now I have implemented them separately as follows.

This is Service1.cs file:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    string GetService1Msg()
    {  
        return "Service1";
    }
}
```

This is Service2.cs file:

```
public class Service2 : IService2
{
    string GetService2Msg()
    {  
        return "Service2";
    }
}
```

My intention here is to expose above two as two service contracts/interfaces outside.
Now My question is how to define endpoints for these two service interfaces in app.config of this WCF Servicelibrary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic configuration of two services exposed on Net.Tcp, each with one endpoint for data and endpoint for metadata:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Metadata">
     <serviceMetadata />
    </behavior>
  <serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="Namespace1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="Metadata"> 
    <host>
     <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost/Service1" />
     </baseAddresses>
     <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="Namespace1.IService1" />
     <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </host>
  </service>
  <service name="Namespace2.Service2" behaviorConfiguration="Metadata"> 
    <host>
     <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost/Service2" />
     </baseAddresses>
     <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="Namespace2.IService2" />
     <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

You still need some code to host your services.

Comment: The endpoints described by you are good for me. But if I have to use http binding, then how can I define endpoints. Should I need to give separate urls for each service?